# Plane covered by disks

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $U$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Suppose that there is a positive real number $r$ such that $D(p:r)\subset U$ for any $p\in U$. ($D(p:r)$ is open disk)

Prove that $U=\mathbb{R^2}$.

This statement implies that squares cover the plane $\mathbb{R^2}$.

But I don't konw how to prove this.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hint: What can you say about the boundary of $U$?

Comment: Notice that $U$ must be not empty.
Let $p \in U$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ then $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}^*, \dfrac{x - p}{n} \in D(0, r)$.
prove by induction that $\forall k \in \{0,\ldots,  n\}, p + k \dfrac{x - p}{n} \in U$.

Comment: As stated by the OP, $U = \emptyset$ works (logically). But, the key  point that Essaidi is using is that $\Bbb R$ satisfies the Archimedean property,